# Как сделать доступными глобальные переменные в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Как сделать доступными глобальные переменные, которые я объявил в си, в ассемблере? Делаю в visual studio 2015.
Надо именно глобальные переменные, как работать с указателями, я уже разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, я разобрался.

Вот так объявляем глобальную переменную в си

```
extern "C" {char str_1[50];}
```

А вот так объявляем переменную в ассемблерном коде

```
.data
extern  str_1:dword
```

Вроде бы, работает как надо)